# How do I get to this handy debugging screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, debugging

While debugging a web page in Chrome, my finger slipped and I pressed a combination of something (around the F12 key) on the keyboard.  I got this screen:

[image]

Which is incredibly handy for developing mobile pages and actually something I've been looking for.  Now I can't figure out how I got this.

So, how do I get back to this screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, press F12 to open up the developer console.

Then, to show the device choice options:

```
Ctrl + Shift + M in Windows/Linux
Cmd + Shift + M in Mac
```

To show the ruler, go to:

> Under Settings > General > Show rulers a ruler can be enabled which
>   will be displayed when you hover over or select an element in the
>   Elements panel.

All keyboard shortcuts for Chrome can be found here:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/shortcuts

Comment: that's wrong.. the screen he's talking about is the emulation screen

Comment: Yup,  just updated my answer after that, same time as your comment :)

Answer (score 3):

That's the emulation screen, press F12 then click on the mobile in the top left corner.